# Vanity not works with MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis, vanity

I tried to install Vanity gem for my rails 2.3.5 application and I want to use MySQL for vanity. Everything is working great when I configure it with redis but when I change the config file to use mysql :

```
development:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: mysql
  host: localhost
  database: vanity
  username: root
  password:
```

I get the following error :

```
Showing
/Users/dries/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/vanity-1.5.3/lib/vanity/templates/_ab_test.erb where line #1 raised:

Vanity::Adapters::ActiveRecordAdapter is not missing constant
VanityConversion! Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% score = experiment.score %> 
2: <table> 
3:   <caption> 
4:     <%= experiment.conclusion(score).join(" ") %></caption> 

Trace of template
inclusion:
/Users/dries/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/vanity-1.5.3/lib/vanity/templates/_experiment.erb,
/Users/dries/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/vanity-1.5.3/lib/vanity/templates/_experiments.erb,
/Users/dries/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/vanity-1.5.3/lib/vanity/templates/_report.erb
```

I added in environment file development.rb :

```
Vanity.playground.establish_connection :development
Vanity.playground.collecting = true
```

So it has to do something with the adapter included in the vanity gem, because redis is working perfect. Somebody who knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figured out the cause for this yet, but I got it to work by being more explicit with the class names for the has_many associations in the active_record_adapter.rb file:

```
has_many :vanity_metric_values, :class_name => "Vanity::Adapters::ActiveRecordAdapter::VanityMetricValue"
has_many :vanity_conversions, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Vanity::Adapters::ActiveRecordAdapter::VanityConversion"
```

Edit: This seems to break the migration process when booting up vanity for the first time (which I'm working to fix!), but may help you on your way to a solution.

Comment: This was fixed in Vanity 1.8.4, see https://github.com/assaf/vanity/blob/1-8-stable/CHANGELOG